# How to add new source files from a subdirectory using CMake

Tags: qt, cmake, static-linking

I am using Qt in a way that the Qt-related files are in a separate subdirectory called "*GUI*", and I am using CMake, the relevant part of it is shown below:

```
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES} GUI/include main/include)

add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE QOBJECT_HEADERS
    "GUI/include/*.h"
)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QOBJECT_SOURCES
    "GUI/*.cpp"
)

QT5_WRAP_CPP(hdr_moc ${QOBJECT_HEADERS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}  -std=c++11 -Wall")

add_executable(simGUI main/sim_GUI.cpp ${QOBJECT_SOURCES}
    ${hdr_moc})
# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(simGUI Qt5::Widgets)
```

Basically this setup works, but when I add a new file (something like an custom widget), the new file compiles OK, but in the linking phase the new object is not found.

I used to delete the build subdirectory, and after that everything works fine.

Am I doing something wrong with CMake? I guess the symptoms are caused by some caching problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [CMake's documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem):

> We do not recommend using `GLOB` to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

The typical approach is to list all files manually.

Comment: OK, thanks. Although I think there are ways to notice that something is new. The strange, however, is that the new file is !compiled! but not !linked!.

Comment: @katang: I've never used `GLOB` because of this drawback, so I cannot say how does it work. We may assume CMake generates compilation rules basing on `*.cpp` pattern but cannot apply similar pattern on link step.

Comment: This latter one is even more strange for me. After the compilation phase new objects are created, the object files are definitely new, and created by the CMake system. BTW: I used GLOB because I used to forget to edit the list of the source files. It looks like the best bet is to delete build subdirectory after adding/removing a new file.

Comment: @katang: removing build dir for small projects may be good enough, but when it becomes bigger and bigger, you will lose time for compilation.