# How to make Qt Creator show cmake target_include_directories?

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, header-files

Working with fairly recent versions of CMake, I like to use `target_include_directories`. However, when I just do this, Qt Creator will not display any header files.

How can I write a `CMakeLists.txt` with `target_include_directories` such that Qt Creator will show header files without adding them manually?

Comment: [CMake + Qt Creator: Add header files to project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377233/cmake-qt-creator-add-header-files-to-project-files)

Comment: Both answers suggest to add headers manually. Can I not get Qt Creator to list those headers that I add in cmake using `target_include_directories`?

Comment: See: [How to add new C++ header and source files in Qt Creator with CMake build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61958550/how-to-add-new-c-header-and-source-files-in-qt-creator-with-cmake-build), but that is apparently discouraged as mentioned here: [Qt/CMake difficulty with new source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482538/qt-cmake-difficulty-with-new-source-files). I never tried that, I'm just sharing what I found.